# Android Ping - Stop process, not destroy

Tags: android

I need to properly stop the android ping process I started with `Runtime.getRuntime.exec();`

I have tried using `android.os.Process.sendSignal(pid, SIGNAL_QUIT);`however nothing happens...sending SIGNAL_KILL is the same as `process.destroy();`and I get a hard kill losing the ping statistics. I need the statistics.

It seems this should be possible as I see other apps doing it.

I have also tried an Outputstream and sending the \u0003 character.

How can I do the equivalent of ^C in the terminal emulator in my app?